# Prove that there are $(b_1+1)(b_2+1)\cdots(b_k+1)$ numbers $n$ which satisfy these two conditions

Tags: number-theory

> Let $N=2^a p_1^{b_1} p_2^{b_2} \cdots p_k^{b_k}$. Prove that there are $(b_1+1)(b_2+1)\cdots(b_k+1)$ numbers $n$ which satisfy these two conditions: $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\leq N$ and $N-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is divisible by $n$.

If $n$ is odd, then $$N-\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} \equiv N \equiv 0 \pmod{n}.$$ On the other hand, if $n$ is even then let $n = 2k$ and we have $$N-\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} = N-\dfrac{2k(2k+1)}{2} = N-k(2k+1) \equiv N-k \equiv 0 \pmod{2k}.$$ Thus $N \equiv k \pmod{2k}$ and so $N = k+2km = k(2m+1)$ for some positive integer $m$. Therefore, $k$ divides $N$. In either case, $n$ contains only prime factors of $N$ in its prime factorization.

I didn't see a way to count all the possibilities for $n$ because of the restriction that $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} \leq N$. How can we continue?

Comment: Hint: The expression $(b_1+1)(b_2+1)\cdots(b_k+1)$ gives number of odd divisors of $N$.